# How can I make a symmetric tridiagonal matrix in Python?

Tags: python

There is a new **edit** at the end of the topic.
I'm new in Python and I would like to know how could I make a simple tridiagonal matrix NxN.
I have three vectors that will be updated over a loop.

I'm working with something like this:
[image: Example]

Note: I just want to know how zeros and what Python parameters I could use to adjust this.
Well, I have two codes here, the first one I wrote in Fortran and it works fine. And the second is what I tried to write in Python.

Fortran:

```
do i=2,n-1
  do j=2,n-1
    if (i.eq.j) then

      D(i,j+1)=-u_med(i+1)/(delta_r(i)*delta_r(i+1))

      t1 =u_med(i+1)/(delta_r(i)*delta_r(i))

      t2 = u_med(i)/(delta_r(i)*delta_r(i))

      D(i,j)= t1 + t2 + V(i)

      D(i+1,j)=-u_med(i+1)/(delta_r(i)*delta_r(i+1))

    end if

  end do
end do
```

Python:

```
for i in range(2,n):
  for j in range(2,n):
    if i == j:
      D[i][j+1] = - u_med[i+1]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i+1])
      t1 = u_med[i+1]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i])
      t2 = u_med[i]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i])
      D[i][j]= t1 + t2 + V[i]
      D[i+1][j]= - u_med[i+1]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i+1])

t1 = u_med[2]/(delta_r[1]*delta_r[1])
t2 = 0
D[1][1]= t1 + t2 + V[1]
D[1][2]= - u_med[2]/(delta_r[1]*delta_r[2])
D[2,1]= - u_med[2]/(delta_r[2]*delta_r[1])
t1 = 0
t2 = u_med[n]/(delta_r[n]*delta_r[n])

D[n][n]= t1 + t2 + V[n]
```

Which gives the error:

> D[i][j+1] = - u_med[i+1]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i+1]) ValueError: setting
>   an array element with a sequence.

Example based on the above image:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPsOO.png)

Comments:

For `u_med`:

```
u_med = np.zeros((n,2))
for i in range(2,n):
  tta1 = r[i]*u[i]
  tta2 = r[i-1]*u[i-1]
  u_med[i] = 0.5*(tta1 + tta2)/(r[i] - r[i-1])

u_med[1] = u_med[2]
```

For `delta_r`:

```
delta_r = np.zeros((n-1,2))
for i in range(2,n-1):
  ft1 = r[i+1]*r[i+1]
  ft2 = r[i-1]*r[i-1]
  ft3 = 2*r[i]*(r[i+1] - r[i-1])
  delta_r[i] = math.sqrt(0.125*abs(ft1 - ft2 + ft3))
```

For `r` and `n`:

```
ri=0
n1 = 51

r1 = ri
r2 = 250
hr1 = (r2-r1)/(n1-1)

r = np.zeros((n1,1))
for i in range(n1):
  r[i] = r1 + i*hr1

u = np.zeros((n+1,1))
for i in range(1,n+1):
  i = 1
```

And for `D`:

```
D = npm.zeros((n,n))
```

**Edit**: It seems to be because the `u_med` and `delta_r` are two-dimensional and I'm trying to assign it in `D` with an incompatible shape. It works in Fortran, but how can I approach it differently in Python?

Comment: I think you will eventually run into an OutOfBounds exception as `i+1` will reach `n`. Maybe have `range(2,n-1)` as in your fortran code.

Comment: What are `u_med` and `delta_r`? Can you give an example of each?

Comment: Also, would be useful to know what `u_med` and `delta_r` stand for

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I already edited the topic, if it is still not clear, let me know.

Comment: Please define `u_med` and `delta_r` in the code and specify how you created `D` as well.

Comment: Also, if `D` is a NumPy array the syntax is `D[i, j+1]` and not `D[i][j+1]` and the error means that the right-hand side of your assignment is not a number but a sequence (a list or tuple).

Comment: I already edited the topic.

Comment: "if `D` is a NumPy array the syntax is `D[i, j+1]` and not `D[i][j+1]`". Oh, I did not know that. Thanks!

Comment: More comments: 1. the definition of `r` is missing, we cannot run the code as is. 2. The indexing for NumPy arrays starts at 0 and not at 1. This might help :-)

Comment: @PierredeBuyl I edited the topic again.. But I still can't solve the problem. I'm suspecting it's this `D = npm.zeros((n,n))`... But how can I write this otherwise?

Comment: It seems to be because the `u_med` and `delta_r` are two-dimensional and I'm trying to assign it in `D` with an incompatible shape. It works in Fortran, but how can I approach it differently in Python?

Comment: If you need all ones there's https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tri.html

Answer (score 0):

If you create the diagonals as just arrays or lists, then you could use [numpy.diag()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html) to create diagonal matrices and add them together.

```
D = np.diag(x) + np.diag(x1, 1) + np.diag(x1, -1)
```

to create your matrix. Perhaps something like

```
A = mu[1:]/h[1:]**2 + mu[:1]/h[1:]**2 + U[1:]
B = mu[1:]/ (h[:-1]*h[1:])
D = np.diag(A) + np.diag(B, 1) + np.diag(B, -1)
```

going off of the image you linked.